# factor polynomial with coefficients

Tags: factoring

> Based on a prior question it turned out the roots of the polynomial
>
> $$P(z) = z^2-a\,z-\frac{z}{a}+1$$ are determinded by $z_1 = a$ and
> $z_2 = 1/a$
>
> Naively I fought the Polynomial can be hence factored by $$P_2(z) =
> > (z-a)\,(z-1/a)$$
>
> However, this is wrong. The true factorization is given by  $$P_1(z) =
> > (a-z)\,(a\,z-1)$$
>
> It's quite puzzling me where that deviation comes from.

**Edit**

Really unfortunate:

For Whatever Reason I fought

$$P_1(z)= z+a^2\,z-a\,z^2-a$$

is the same as

$$P_2(z) = z^2-a\,z-\frac{z}{a}+1$$

However, here I had $P_2(z) = \frac{P_1(z)}{-a}$ expecting same factorization for both Polynomials from the program.

The reason for my expectation underlies the fact $P_1$ and $P_2$ have same roots. But their factorization is different? Also what's questionable: why it can't be fixed by multiplying $a$ back.

Comment: What are you talking about? You do have$$(z-a)\left(z-\frac1a\right)=z^2-az-\frac za+1.$$

Comment: Yea that's what I also assumed. But after calculating $z^2-a\,z-\frac{z}{a}+1 -(z-a)\,(z-1/a) \neq 0$ by a program (Matlab) it gave me this factorization instead. It could be, Matlab couldn't find a simplification. But why it does works withe the other factorization?

Comment: That program is wrong you answer is correct @Leon . Maybe some typo mistake you did in that program. Try wolframalpha.com once

Comment: Your "true factorization" is obviously wrong -- you can check that for yourself simply by multiplying out $(a-z)(az-1)$.

Comment: $z^2-a\,z-\frac{z}{a}+1 -(z-a)\,(z-1/a) = 0$  indeed

Comment: If you are only interested in answers provided by some software, then why bother to post questions here? We are human, after all.

Comment: The "true factorization" can be fixed by $p(z)=\frac 1a(a-z)(az-1)$.  But this is not really as good a presentation of this polynomial as the other.

Comment: Yea right. My apologies

Comment: Edited my Question. Fatal error was included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edit the problem is that both polynomial are different. When we divide $$P_1(z)= z+a^2\,z-a\,z^2-a$$ by $a$ we get

$$ \frac{z}{a}+az-z^2-1 $$

This was the error $1$.

Error $2$ - Also if there is a polynomial $ax+b$. If we divide it by $c$ we get $\dfrac{ax+b}{c}$. Remember that if you just divide a expression by some variable/constant the factorization would change. Remember like the case we took factorisation of $ax+b$ won't be same as $\dfrac{ax+b}{c}$. Similarly factorization of$$P_1(z)= z+a^2\,z-a\,z^2-a$$ is not same as factorization of $$ \frac{z}{a}+az-z^2-1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Based from the content from the blockquote, here is my answer

---

Factoring polynomials of the form $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n}a_{n-i}x^{n - i}$$ based on the roots requires the knowledge of the value of $a_{n}$. This is because defining polynomials of degree $n$ requires $n + 1$ conditions. $n$ of them are the roots and $a_{n}$ is the remaining condition. If it is already known that a polynomial is *monic*, or $a_{n} = 1$, then factoring the roots as $$\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(x - x_{i})$$ is a valid factorization. However, if the polynomial is not monic, factor out $a_{n}$ from all terms of the polynomial. This gives a monic polynomial, scaled by $a_{n}$. Factor out the monic polynomial, then combining all yields the factorization of the original polynomial.

For example, consider the function $f(x) = 2x^{2} + 6x + 4$. Notice that the leading coefficient, $a_{n}$, is equal to $2$. Factoring $2$ from $f$, we have $2(x^{2} + 3x + 2)$. let $g(x) = x^{2} + 3x + 2$. By getting the roots of $g$, we get that the roots are $\{-2, -1\}$. Factoring $g$, we have $(x + 2)(x + 1)$. Remember that this is the factorization of $g$ and $f(x) = 2g(x)$, hence, the factorization of $f$ is $2(x + 2)(x + 1)$.